# 2D heatmap of mean values with R

Tags: r, plot, histogram, heatmap

I'm trying to plot something like this, where alpha is intended to be a mean of dat$c per bin:

```
library(ggplot2)

set.seed(1)

dat <- data.frame(a = rnorm(1000), b = rnorm(1000), c = 1/rnorm(1000),
  d = as.factor(sample(c(0, 1), 1000, replace=TRUE)))

# plot
p <- ggplot(dat, environment = environment()) +
  geom_bin2d(aes(x=a, y=b, alpha=c, fill=d),
  binwidth = c(1.0/10, 1.0/10))
```

[image]

but it doesn't look like alpha is correct. Please help

Comment: mean(c) is always the same value... Since it calculates the mean for column c

Comment: I know that mean(c) is the mean of vector c. I just put it as a placeholder because I don't know the answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what you're expecting to see, but this will calculate `mean(dat$c)` in each bin and plot the result.

```
library(ggplot2)
brks <- seq(-5,5,0.1)
lbls <- brks[-1]-0.05
gg.df <- aggregate(c~cut(a, brks, lbls)+cut(b,brks, lbls)+d,dat,FUN=mean)
names(gg.df)[1:2] <- c("a","b")
gg.df$a <- as.numeric(as.character(gg.df$a))
gg.df$b <- as.numeric(as.character(gg.df$b))
ggplot(gg.df, aes(x=a, y=b, alpha=c, fill=d)) + geom_raster() + coord_fixed()
```

[image]

*Edit:* Response to OP's comment.

You could try:

```
dat$c <- with(dat,1/(a^2+b^2))
```

This makes `dat$c` inversely proportional to the radius (distance from (0,0) to the point). Now running the same code as above:

```
gg.df <- aggregate(c~cut(a, brks, lbls)+cut(b,brks, lbls)+d,dat,FUN=mean)
names(gg.df)[1:2] <- c("a","b")
gg.df$a <- as.numeric(as.character(gg.df$a))
gg.df$b <- as.numeric(as.character(gg.df$b))
ggplot(gg.df, aes(x=a, y=b, alpha=c, fill=d)) + geom_raster() + coord_fixed() +
  scale_alpha_continuous(trans="log",breaks=10^(0:3))
```

Produces this, as expected: a plot having tiles with higher `alpha` (less transparent) near the center.

[image]

I needed to use a log scale for `alpha` because the values range over several orders of magnitude.

Comment: Very nice. Thank you. Would that do it also per dat$d? I mean if the same coordinate (a,b) has more than one dat$d then average should be distinct for each of dat$d? How could we visually prove that the solution is working? Maybe use initial data something like 2D sinusoidals?

Comment: See my edits above. Regarding `dat$d`, yes there will be overlapping tiles for bins with more than one `dat$d`. How would you pick one? Honestly at this point it comes down to what are you really try to accomplish. Dealing with the data in the abstract is not going to be productive.